# how to copy files to Library or Document dir in iphone build phase?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, xcodebuild

I want copy some files to `Library` or `Document` in the **Product directory**,
but when I add a build phase and select **Products Directory** in *destination* and *input* my subdir it's like `Library/xxx/`.

When I run the App in the simulator, I found nothing in the *destination* and if I set the *destination* to `Resources`, it will be there.

Can you please tell me why this is happening and how I can make it?

Answer (score 3):

The documents directory should only be accessed at runtime.  To my knowledge you cannot copy items there during building.  What you should do is store those objects that you want in the Documents directory within your bundle and then copy them upon first launch.

Comment: This was true at the time, but with Xcode 4 you can now set a scheme to install an application data package on the Options tab. (Of course, this is only for debugging.)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I don't know if you can do this as part of the build phase.

To get something into the `Documents` directory, I have a method that runs at app startup like this:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.txt"];
BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath writablePath error:&error];
```

That's an incomplete fragment but you probably get the idea. The important thing is the `NSDocumentDirectory` constant.

Comment: The original poster wants to install the files at the same time as when the app is being copied over by Xcode.  I don't think that is possible.  This response has the app installing the files into the Documents directory, at runtime, which isn't the same thing, but the next best thing (AFAIK).

Answer (score -2):

Add a new build phase -> New Copy Files Build Phase in Target

Comment: You can't access any of the iPhone directories from Xcode.  No?

Comment: The interesting bit would be to get the right destination. The question is asking for the Library or Documents path. None of those can be found in the Copy Files Destination Dropdown.